# Can anyone suggest a tool for Performance testing using https and ftps protocols?

Tags: performance, https, jmeter, ftps

I want to run a performance test for https and ftps protocols. I have used JMeter to test http & ftp but the same does not support https and ftps.

Can anyone suggest any good tool?

Answer (score 2):

JMeter supports HTTPS out of the box.

For FTPS you can use:

- http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/
- and create a custom Sampler using [AbstractJavaSamplerClient](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/AbstractJavaSamplerClient.html), see this for an example:

  - http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2011/09/how-to-create-a-java-class-performance-test-using-jmeters-abstractjavasamplerclient/

Comment: Hey, Https worked fine with out issues thanks! But I a bit confused with ftps.. do I have to create a custom sampler or will commons-net do the job.                                                             I am yet to check commons-net but thought will post my question too..

Comment: you have to create subclass of AbstractJavaSamplerClient that uses commons-net as this lib implements ftps protocol

Comment: The current version of JMeter (2.10) supports https